# Ajax is not firing up on h:SelectOneMenu

Tags: ajax, jsp, select

I have two , when there is a change in the selected option in the first select it must fire up an update in the second Select but it is only happening with page load.

**Cliente.xhtml**

```
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="ListaProvincia"  immediate="true" value="#{beanCliente.provincia}">
                        <f:selectItems id="itemProvincia" value="#{beanCliente.listaProvincia}"/>
                        <f:ajax listener="beanCliente.changeCanton()" render="Canton" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel styleClass="optional">Canton</h:outputLabel>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="Canton" value="#{beanCliente.canton}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{beanCliente.listaCantones}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

**beanCliente**

```
public LinkedList getListaCantones() {
    return this.listaCantones;
}

public void setDistrito(int Distrito) {
    this.Distrito = Distrito;
}

public int getDistrito() {
    return Distrito;
}

public void setListaDistrito()throws SNMPExceptions, SQLException {
    String nombre="";
    int id_distrito=0;
    DistritoDB objDB = new DistritoDB();
     LinkedList resultList = new LinkedList();
     for (Iterator iter = objDB.listaDistritos(this.getCanton()).iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
     Distrito di = (Distrito) iter.next();
         id_distrito= di.getID_Distrito();
         nombre=di.getNombre();
     resultList.add(new SelectItem(id_distrito, nombre));
     }
    this.listaCantones = resultList;
}
```